# Throttle calls to ItemProcessor in Spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I've created spring batch which reads from flat file and process the data using ItemProcessor before writing in the DB using ItemWriter, everything so for works fine.

The problem now I need to control the number of times "**Process**" method is called for processing the data, my itemprocessor calls some API with details, the API will take some time to respond (not sure about the timeout), Hence, i should not overload the API with new messages. I need to control the calls to API, e.g ***X  number of call in y Sec*** if it reaches, i need to wait for ***Z sec*** before resuming the activity.

I am not sure how to achieve this in spring batch, I am looking at implementing chunklistener in processor to track the calls. However, I am looking for a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a listener to do this.

If you do not define an asynchronous taskexecutor in your stop, then the whole processing is completely sequentially.

It will read an item, process an item, reads the next item, processes it until it as read and processed as many items as you defined in your commitsize (-> the size of your chunks). After that, it will put those items into a list and forward this list to the writer. This process will be executed, until all elements have been read, processed, and finally written.

If you would like to process your chunks in parallel, then you can define an asynchronous taskexecutor.

If you define an AsyncTaskExeutor in your step, you are able to configure the number of threads this TaskExecutor manages/creates. Moreover, you can also define the throttlelimit of your step which defines the number of chunks that can be be processed in parallel.